# using ZTE MF1 HSPA USB Modem in Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: usb-modem

My ZTE MF192 HSPA USB Orange Modem(black) came with Linux driver setup packages which I installed one by one. The modem now blinks with a blue light but that's all. I've tried the Mobile Broadband settings on the Network icon on the task bar but nothing seems to work.
I"ve tried using mode_switch but it requires an internet connection to install(which is what am trying to set up.)
I've tried everything but nothing seems to work. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

What I did in order for my vodafone usb stick, which is of ZTE HSPA + usb stick, to work was:

1. Go to linux folder and copy paste the .tar.gz file to Downloads
2. Use `cd` to go to the downloads which is `cd Downloads`
3. Unzip tar.gz file which is `tar xvzf filename.tar.gz`
4. Install config file which is `./install.sh` in my case